# Scheduler tasks registration design

Tags: .net, architecture, mef

I have an architectural question.

Let's say we have a scheduler and a number of subsystems. Some of these subsystems can have actions, that should be able to be executed by scheduler.

We have two ways to implement this registration of scheduler tasks.

One way is to have a method in each subsystem, called like `RegisterSchedulerTasks`, that will be called by bootstrapper in application during application start. In this method we will call something like static `Scheduler` class like this:

```
void Handler1(){
}

void Handler2(){
}

void RegisterSchedulerTasks()
{
  Scheduler.RegisterHandler( "E1", Handler1 );
  Scheduler.RegisterHandler( "E2", Handler2 );
}
```

`"E1"` and `"E2"` are names of tasks, that will have corresponding settings in scheduler config.

Another approach is to use, for example, MEF.
Each subsystem will export a set of `ISchedulerTask`s, and it will not register these tasks imperatively.
And on the other side of application we will have `SchedulerTasksRegistry`, that will import a set of these `ISchedulerTask`s.

In all approaches we will have a map in config, that will contain scheduling timeline for each task, identified in both approaches by its name.

I am inclining to the second approach, but do not have enough arguments for it. Probably the only argument is that the first approach means higher static coupling of subsystems.

Am I right, is the second approach better? What are arguments for any of these approaches?

Comment: My question is not about scheduler only. For example, similar question can be asked about some factories - we can this factory be built implicitly by means of MEF, that will search for all available implementations of interface that is returned by factory, and on the other hand we can create this factory imperatively with some kind of hard-coded switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would use the 'Chain of Responsability' pattern. This pattern

> 'Avoids coupling the sender of a request to the receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. Chain the reciving object and pass the request along the chain until an object handles it.'

An example of the use of this pattern can be found [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand clearly how to use this pattern in my case. Can you explain, please?